# finding a value in dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, find

I am trying to print out a message.
If a word in dictionary is not found then it should print out a message instead of giving an error.
What I thought is

```
if bool(bool(dictionary[word])) == True:
    return dictionary[word]
else:
    print 'wrong'
```

but it does not work when I write something that is not in dictionary instead it gives something like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    translate_word('hous')
  File "H:\IND104\final\Project 4 - Italian-Spanish Translator\trial 1.py", line 21, in translate_word
    if bool(bool(dictionary[word])) == True:
KeyError: 'hous'
```

So how can I print out an error message thanks.

Comment: You should *never* do `bool(bool(x)) == True`. Just `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is a `try`/`except` block:

```
try:
    return dictionary[word]
except KeyError:
    print 'wrong'
    return None
```

Comment: after I use this one it also continues to read rest of the lines, how can I stop reading the rest of it after I use this one?

Comment: @Sarp that's a different question

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `in` operator to test whether or not a key is in the dictionary. With your variable names this becomes:

```
if word in dictionary:
```

If you wish to check for the presence of the key and retrieve the value in one go you can use the [`get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method:

```
value = dictionary.get(word)
if value is not None:
    ...
```

You can supply your own default value to `get()` which is returned if the key is not found. Then you could write your code like this:

```
print dictionary.get(word, 'wrong')
```

Comment: `is not` is also an operator: `if value is not None`

Comment: @chepner Sorry, I'm not fluent in Python!

Comment: Just FYI :) It is odd in that it is two words and requires special language support. After all, you can't compose `not` with anything else (you couldn't say `not <`, `not ==`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
if word in dictionary:
    return dictionary[word]
else:
    print("wrong")
```

Comment: after I use this one it also continues to read rest of the lines, how can I stop reading the rest of it after I use this one?

Comment: @SarpKaya: are you doing this in a loop? Then use `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing a dictionary assumes that the key is already there, in order to test if the key is in the dictionary, try this:

```
#Check to see if a key is in a dictionary
dictionary = {'key' : 123}
if 'key' in dictionary:
 #Do something
else:
 #Do something else
```

The [key] in [dictionary] is now the favoured syntax over the previous has_key([key]) dictionary method: [reference](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key)

Answer (score 0):

Time to learn some exception handling:

```
try:
    some_stuff()
except:
    print "Sorry, an error occured"
```